# JUnit 5 Dynamic Test

Tags: java, junit5

I'm getting this error

```
XQTest.lambda$null$0:51 » NoClassDefFound Could not initialize class weblogic....
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class weblogic.xml.query.parsers.StAXFactoryHelper
```

And here is my test:

```
@TestFactory
public Stream<DynamicTest> XQueryDynamicTestsFromStream() throws IOException {
    ArrayList<Tuple4> tuple4 = buildTest.buildTestFromResources();

    System.out.println("TEST");


    return tuple4.stream()
                 .map(phrs ->
                      DynamicTest.dynamicTest(
                          "Test XQuery: (" + phrs.a.substring(phrs.a.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1) + ")"
                          , () -> {
                              int idx = tuple4.indexOf(phrs);
                              String transformer = tuple4.get(idx).a;
                              String testPath = tuple4.get(idx).b;
                              String inpFile = tuple4.get(idx).c;
                              String expFile = tuple4.get(idx).d;

                              XQueryTester tester = new XQueryTester(transformer, testPath);

                              if (inpFile.contains("HDR")) {
                                  assertTrue(tester.testHeader(inpFile, expFile));
                              } else if (inpFile.contains("PAY")) {
                                  causing error->assertTrue(tester.testBody(inpFile, expFile));
                              }


                          }
                      )
                 );
}
```

For your information: I'm testing XQueries and wrote therefore my own Engine `XQueryTester` which I instantiate as `"tester"`.

Depending on the files, which I search with `XQueryTest (buildTest)`, I'm running a header or payload test.

Comment: Looks like the JAR that contains `weblogic.xml.query.parsers.StAXFactoryHelper` is not on the class path when the tests run. If that's so, this has nothing to do with JUnit.